# How to parameterize a bivariate Normal distribution output for a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normal-distribution, parameterization

For a neural net where the output is a Gaussian distribution, the output is usually parameterized as $(\mu=O_1, \sigma^2=e^{O_2})$. That is to say, the neural net will output the mean, and also output the **log** of the variance $O_2$. This is the natural choice to make all the outputs fit on the real line, and works well when training the neural net.

However, I want to output a bivariate Gaussian distribution (with 2 means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, 2 variances $v_1$ and $v_2$, and a correlation $\rho$). The problem is, there are several natural ways to parameterize the variances and correlation (such that everything is a real number).

To name just 2:

1. Each parameter gets its own output.
   \begin{align}
   v_1 &= e^{O_1} \\
   v_2 &= e^{O_2} \\
   \rho &= tanh(O_3)
   \end{align}
2. Say that
   \begin{align}
   X_1 &= Z_1 + Z_c \\
   X_2 &= Z_2 + Z_c
   \end{align}
   where $Z_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0, e^{O_i})$ are "private information" and $Z_c\sim\mathcal{N}(0, e^{O_3})$ is a "shared" gaussian information. Then we will have that
   \begin{align}
   v_1 &= e^{O_1} + e^{O_3} \\
   v_2 &= e^{O_2} + e^{O_3} \\
   \rho &= \frac{e^{O_3}}{\sqrt{v_1 \cdot v_2}}
   \end{align}

Which of these ways of parameterizing the output bivariate Gaussian distribution would be best? Or is there a better way? My main criteria would be what works best when training a neural network.

Personally, I think that the second way would be better, since the choice of correlation should be closely tied to the choice of variances, and the "private information"/"shared information" model for a bivariate Gaussian seems very natural.

Finally, I'm satisfied with just the bivariate case, but I may as well ask what one could do in the multivariate case?

Answer (score 4):

For the multivariate case, you could try outputting a vector $d$ of diagonal entries and an $n\times k$ matrix $R$, and let $\Sigma = \text{diag}(d) + RR^T$. This would be easy to sample, easy to backpropagate through, and also you can trade off computation cost with expressivity (as $k \rightarrow n$, you have a full covariance matrix).

Comment: but how do you guarantee that $\Sigma$ is positive define?